# Strip modifiers from decltype(*this) for use in trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++20, decltype

Let's say I have Base and Derived classes:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual auto DoSomething(const Base&) const -> decltype(*this) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    const Derived& DoSomething(const Base&) const override; // OK, but not what I want
    // Derived DoSomething(const Base&) const override;     // ERROR, but I want this
};
```

The uncommented code compiles fine, and works fine if you fill it out. But I don't want to return a const reference from `DoSomething()`. Is there any way to strip the modifiers from the trailing return type in the base class declaration? I've tried a few methods from `<type_traits>` (`remove_cvref_t`, etc), but they seem to evaluate the type to `Base`, which creates a conflicting return type.

If what I'm trying to do is not possible, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, you can make make `Base::DoSomething` return type `Base` with [`std::remove_cvref_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref):

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual auto DoSomething(const Base&) const -> std::_remove_cvref_t<decltype(*this)> = 0;
};
```

However, a function that overrides another function must return either the same type as overridden function or a [covariant type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types). Quoting from cppreference:

> Two types are covariant if they satisfy all of the following
> requirements:
>
> - both types are pointers or references (lvalue or rvalue) to classes. Multi-level pointers or references are not allowed.
> - the referenced/pointed-to class in the return type of `Base::f()` must be an unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of
>   the referenced/pointed-to class of the return type of `Derived::f()`.
> - the return type of `Derived::f()` must be equally or less cv-qualified than the return type of `Base::f()`.

So yes, if `Base::DoSomething` will return `Base`, any overrides must also return `Base`. If `Base::DoSomething` will return `Base&` or `Base*`, you can override that with `Derived& Derived::DoSomething` (or respectively `Derived*`).

---

What you want to do would be very breaking from compiler point of view. Imagine the following code:

```
//interface.hpp
struct Base { // sizeof(Base) == 8
    virtual Base foo(); // could return through a register
}; 

//implementation.hpp
struct Derived: public Base { // sizeof(Derived) == 32 at least
    std::string x;
    Derived foo() override; // too big to return through register, must return through stack
}; 

//interface_user.cpp
#include "interface.hpp" // doesn't know about implementation.hpp

void bar(Base& myBase) {
    Base b = myBase.foo(); // where is it returned? through a register or the stack? compiler knows for sure it should be a register, but...
}
```

Not to mention the obvious violation of Liskov's subsitution principle.